# How to delete all records in the importexport_importdata table?

Tags: import, product-import

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
```

I am doing a product's export from Magento 2.4.2-p1 and importing this into Magento 2.4.5-p1 but I get the following Error:

General system exception happened
Additional data: Error in data structure: entity values are mixed

I googled the Error and this article here seems to suggest to:

It is as simple as delete all records in importexport_importdata table and then, try to execute the importation process again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278535/magento-cronjob-import-error-in-data-structure-entity-codes-are-mixed

**How do I do that?** *Can I do it in phpMyAdmin? Would someone be able to provide exact steps for this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute Mysql delete query (assuming mysql as you have asked for phpMyAdmin)

1. Select the database in phpMyAdmin.

   OR execute mysql query for selecting database:

   ```
    use <db-name>;
   ```
2. Delete all records from importexport_importdata table.

   ```
    delete from importexport_importdata;
   ```